# Cypress how to store values yielded by a function into a variable

Tags: javascript, return-value, cypress

This has been bugging me from a long time. I am not well versed with javascript. Here it goes:

1. How do i store return value of a function into a variable:

   lenValue = cy.get(selector).children().length

Above line of code returns undefined But when i try following in cypress test runner console then I get a valid output:

```
cy.$$(selector).children().length --> gives me correct number
```

2. How to return value from inside a then function and catch it to reuse later:

file1.js

```
function a(selector, attrName){
cy.get(selector).then(function ($el){
return $el.attr(attrName));
}
```

file2.js

```
state = file1Obj.a('#name','name')
```

Comment: Just to check since you are new to javascript, do you have lenValue declared as a variable anywhere using `var` `let` or `const`?  so like `let lenValue = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aeischeid shows you the wrong way to do it.

His code works only for a static site, but web pages are rarely static. As soon as API fetches are involved, **lucky timing** goes out the window and the test bombs.

This is why Cypress commands have automatic retry. Otherwise we could just build tests with jQuery.

---

Since `cy.$$(selector).children().length --> gives me correct number`, use that inside the helper function.

```js
function a(selector, attrName) {
  return cy.$$(selector).attr(attrName);      // jQuery methods used
}
```

Or

```js
function a(selector, attrName) {
  return Cypress.$(selector).attr(attrName);  // jQuery methods used
}
```

But be aware that jQuery only handles static pages, it does not retry if the attribute that you want to query arrives slowly.

For that use a command

```
cy.get('#name')
  .should('have.attr', 'name')     // retries until name exists
  .then(name => {                  // guaranteed to have a value
    // use name here
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @SteveZodiac I used jquery to achieve what i desired. Will definetly note your point of retries and keep a close look on failure reasons. Thank you once again for the explanation.

Comment: No problem. You're probably ok with a name attribute, it would be hard-coded.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing makes complete sense, but simply put, you cannot. (per the docs).
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases/#Return-Values

You can, however, use aliases to accomplish what (I think) you're after.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases/#Aliases

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example from a cypress test I have that seems pretty relevant

```js
    let oldDescription;
    cy.get('input#description').should(($input) => {
      oldDescription = $input.val();
    });
    let randomDescription = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    cy.get('input#description').clear().type(randomDescription);
    cy.get('input#description')
      .parents('.ant-table-row')
      .contains('Save').click();

    cy.get('input#description').should('not.exist');
    cy.contains(`${randomDescription}`);
    cy.contains(`${oldDescription}`).should('not.exist');
```

because oldDescription is set inside of an asyncronous callback it isn't safe to expect it to be set, farther down the code outside of that callback, but in a lot of cases with cypress you end up having some other .get call or thing that waits, effectively pausing the code long enough that you can get away with not worrying about it.

Comment: This is fundamentally a bad idea to expect other code to give your promise time to resolve. "Get away with not worrying about it" is not how this should work and is exactly how to create flakey tests.

Comment: yep. thus why "it isn't safe", but on the other hand cypress asyc isn't like network async. There isn't some huge degree of variation and with e2e DOM reads. the test I pulled this example from has never actually failed. It is an example of a flaky test that isn't actually flaky.